# How to encode a list of URI's as a string?

Tags: c++, html, qt, url, uri

I need to store a list of http URI's as a single string. The language/toolkit shouldn't matter, but for completeness the language is C++ and the primary toolkit I'm using is Qt (I'm actually trying to get a list of strings into a single QString because it's one of the few Qt types that doesn't get pickled in a non-human readable way when it goes into a QDataStream => QVariant => QSettings.)

Is there a 'safe' character that I can delimit this list of URI strings with?

Comment: How about a JSON encoded array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether the URIs are percent-encoded or not (e.g. like when you type a space in a URL  in the URL bar and the browser replaces it with a %20).

If they are encoded, there are many characters you can use, even a single space. If not, I don't think there's any "safe" character like this. In that case, maybe you could encode the URIs before storing them together, and possibly decode them later.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a space so long as all spaces in the URI are encoded to `+`. You could also use a combination like `%~` or any other combination of a `%` followed by a character that cannot appear after a `%` in a URI. Using a newline character or tab would work too.